# golang module name change causes local tests to fail

Tags: go, github, go-modules

I have a fork of someone's code. Their module name is formatted like so:

```
module github.com/foo/bar/v3
```

I've made some changes locally and have updated the local `go.mod` to be `v4` instead of `v3` but this now causes the running of the tests locally to fail (see below, I've genericized the output).

> Note: the `go.sum` at this point is empty.

```
$ go test -v

go: finding module for package github.com/foo/bar/v3
go: found github.com/foo/bar/v3 in github.com/foo/bar/v3 v3.0.0
# github.com/foo/bar/v4_test [github.com/foo/bar/v4.test]
./some_test.go:232:19: x.Y undefined (type *package.Example has no field or method Y)
FAIL    github.com/foo/bar/v4 [build failed]
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to locate the actual v3 version of the package, and thus updating the go.sum to include it?

I can see from the test file that this package uses a different package name (e.g. `package foo_test`) so it doesn't rely on the exported data structures to exist when writing their test code. So maybe that's why this happens? it sees the reference to `x.Y` and then goes to lookup `x` in github.

But then I'm not sure why the test would run fine when I was using the v3 reference in the go.mod file?

Any ideas on what's happening here and what the right process should be for bumping a go module when you're working on a forked project?

Thanks.

Comment: You changed the module name, did you change all the relevant import statements as well?

Comment: @JimB OMG! What a bell end I've been ‍♂️  What makes this worse is that I literally was reading this in the go blog the other day when refreshing my memory on go module versioning. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your `module` name in `go.mod` file, you have to replace all your `import` path with the updated `module` name.

As you replaced your module `github.com/foo/bar/v3` with `github.com/foo/bar/v4`, you must `find and replace` all your reference of `github.com/foo/bar/v3` with `github.com/foo/bar/v4` throughout the whole project.

Then your `$ go test -v` should run properly.